# Regex to extract links with digits in selenium

Tags: python, regex, selenium, beautifulsoup

The following is a list of links.

```
<a class="table-link" href="/tasks/document/new">Should review
</a></td>
<a class="table-link" href="/tasks/document/58324">Should review
</a></td>
<td>
<a class="table-link" href="/tasks/document/58325">AFCO certificate
</a></td>
<td>
<a class="table-link" href="/tasks/document/58325">Document Task
</a></td>
<td>
<a class="table-link" href="/tasks/document/58326">Pending
</a></td>
<td>
<a class="table-link" href="/tasks/document/58327">Cami  ltd
</a></td>
<td>
<a class="table-link" href="/tasks/document/58328">29 Sep 14:57
```

I want to extract all those links which end in digits and containing `/tasks/document`. The output should as follows:

```
 <a class="table-link" href="/tasks/document/58324">
    <a class="table-link" href="/tasks/document/58325">
    <a class="table-link" href="/tasks/document/58326">
    <a class="table-link" href="/tasks/document/58327">
    <a class="table-link" href="/tasks/document/58328">
```

I am using the following code `driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[href*='/tasks/document/']")`

How do I modify it to read digits only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done using BeautifulSoup as follows:

```
html = """    
<a class="table-link" href="/tasks/document/new">Should review</a></td>
<a class="table-link" href="/tasks/document/58324">Should review/a></td>
<td>
<a class="table-link" href="/tasks/document/58325">AFCO certificate</a></td>
<td>
<a class="table-link" href="/tasks/document/58325">Document Task</a></td>
<td>
<a class="table-link" href="/tasks/document/58326">Pending</a></td>
<td>
<a class="table-link" href="/tasks/document/58327">Cami  ltd</a></td>
<td>
<a class="table-link" href="/tasks/document/58328">29 Sep 14:57"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup        
import re

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for a in soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile(r'\/tasks\/document\/\d+')):
    print a
```

This would display:

```
<a class="table-link" href="/tasks/document/58324">Should review</a>
<a class="table-link" href="/tasks/document/58325">AFCO certificate</a>
<a class="table-link" href="/tasks/document/58325">Document Task</a>
<a class="table-link" href="/tasks/document/58326">Pending</a>
<a class="table-link" href="/tasks/document/58327">Cami  ltd</a>
<a class="table-link" href="/tasks/document/58328">29 Sep 14:57</a>
```

If you just need the actual `href` then use:

```
print a['href']
```

Giving you:

```
/tasks/document/58324
/tasks/document/58325
/tasks/document/58325
/tasks/document/58326
/tasks/document/58327
/tasks/document/58328
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option in selenium.

If you want, you can use selenium to get the source code and feed it to [beautifulsoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#beautiful-soup-documentation) parser. Then you can use regexps to find the wanted elements.